# How to copy a certain data from multiple excel file with diffrent name into one master excel file

Tags: excel

I need help to compile a certain data from multiple excel file with a different name onto one sheets (excel file located at certain location folder). The data from each file that i want to grap :

1) B69 until E69 & I69

2) B75 until E75 & I75

And compile it into below format  (summary) file: each row differentiate by diffetrent excels file name :

```
Title   Title   Title   Title   Title   Title   Title   Title   Title   Title
B69     C69     D69     E69     I69     B75     C75     D75     E75     I75
B69     C69     D69     E69     I69     B75     C75     D75     E75     I75
B69     C69     D69     E69     I69     B75     C75     D75     E75     I75
B69     C69     D69     E69     I69     B75     C75     D75     E75     I75
B69     C69     D69     E69     I69     B75     C75     D75     E75     I75
```

I do this by daily basis & the data that i need to compile 100+ excel file a day.
Really hoping if some one could provide me a script to run macro on this precedure

Answer (score 0):

see http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/filter.html
xlutils combines xlrd and xlwt